# Question about the Christoffel Symbol

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors

Wikipedia says that we have a Christoffel Symbol of the Second Kind, such that:
$$\Gamma_{ij}^k=\frac{\partial \textbf{e}_i}{\partial x^j}\cdot\textbf{e}^k$$
Which we can convert into a Christoffel Symbol of the First Kind as so:
$$\Gamma_{kij}=\frac{\partial \textbf{e}_i}{\partial x^j}\cdot\textbf{e}_k$$
I undestand the whole procedure up to that part. What I don't understand is how it say that 'rearranging' we get:
$$\Gamma_{ij}^k\textbf{e}_k=\frac{\partial \textbf{e}_i}{\partial x^j}$$

Comment: You need to fix the indices in all your equations. You need $i$, $j$, and $k$ on the right-hand side of the first two equations, and there should not be an upper index on $\mathbf e$. The last equation should read $$\frac{\partial\mathbf e_i}{\partial x^j} = \sum \Gamma^k_{ij}\mathbf e_k$$ (and please don't use dot where there is no dot product of vectors). Once you get the first equation with correct indices (and remember that $\mathbf e_k$ are assumed to be an orthonormal basis, I presume), this follows just from orthonormality.  Learn from a text, not from Wikipedia.

Comment: I was half asleep when I wrote this question, I've fixed the equations. I am not assuming an orthonormal basis.

Comment: Is ${\bf e}^k$ the dual basis or the bi-orthogonal (contragredient?) basis? That is, is ${\bf e}^k({\bf e}_j)=\delta_{jk}$ or $g({\bf e}^k,{\bf e}_j)=\delta_{jk}$? It seems like the dual basis, as the last formula works best if ${\bf e}_k{\bf e}^k=I$.

Comment: I'm fairly new at this, but I don't think so. I was thinking arbitrary basis vectors $\textbf{e}_i$, with $\textbf{e}^i=g^{ij}\textbf{e}_j$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\mathbf e_i$ are the given frame (basis), then $\mathbf e^i$ will be the dual basis. These covectors "eat" vectors and spit out numbers. In particular,  $\langle\mathbf e^k,\mathbf e_i\rangle = \delta^k_i$. So if we apply $\mathbf e^k$ to the linear combination $\sum a^i\mathbf e_i$, we get
$$\langle \mathbf e^k,\sum a^i\mathbf e_i\rangle = \sum a^i\langle\mathbf e^k,\mathbf e_i\rangle = \sum a^i\delta^k_i = a^k.$$
Thus, setting $\Gamma^k_{ij} = \langle \mathbf e^k,\dfrac{\partial\mathbf e_i}{\partial x^j}\rangle$, we do in fact get
$$\frac{\partial\mathbf e_i}{\partial x^j} = \sum \Gamma^k_{ij}\mathbf e_k.$$
(Once again, I find the dot in the first equation totally confusing and misleading.)

We can identify the dual space with the original vector space using the Riemannian metric by setting $\langle\tilde{\mathbf w},\mathbf v \rangle = \mathbf w\cdot\mathbf v$. This means that $\langle\tilde{\mathbf e}_k,\mathbf e_i \rangle = \mathbf e_k\cdot \mathbf e_i = g_{ki}$. In order to make this come out equal to $\delta^k_i$, we must take the linear combination
$$\mathbf e^k = \sum g^{kj}\tilde{\mathbf e}_j,$$
for then we have
$$\langle \mathbf e^k,\mathbf e_i\rangle = \sum g^{kj}\mathbf e_j\cdot \mathbf e_i = \sum g^{kj}g_{ki} = \delta^k_i.$$